# What is the cause

Tags: java

Here goes my first question. First of all I'm new with Java and still struggling to understand events. I have JTable with a custom model that extends AbstractTableModel, a CustomTableModelHandler that implements TableModelListener and a custom TableCellRenderer in order to show some custom tool tips (combination of data from different columns). The user can only make single row selection and I checked the option autocreaterowsorter. When removing a row I use this method:

```
public void removeRow(int modelIndex) {
    fireTableRowsDeleted(modelIndex, modelIndex);
    rowData.remove(modelIndex);
}
```

The reason why I first fire the data change event is that I want to update a JLabel with a text that contains data from the row I'm about to delete (probably there is a more elegant way). I'm always passing the model index row, I've tried clearing the selection in the view but that didn't help. I can't seem to reproduce the error 100% of the times, but it seems it happens most of the times after I edit a row, there's a column sorting active and then delete a row (this is actually the action after which the error occurs).

So, the question is: how can I tell what is the cause of my issue? The entire code is a bit too big to post it here, but I can provide it if someone wants to have a look at it.

The error (which appears lots of time):

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
        at Contacts.ContactsGUI$CustomTableModel.getValueAt(ContactsGUI.java:1975)
        at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2686)
        at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5703)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2072)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:1974)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1770)
        at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
        at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
        at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason why I first fire the data change event is that I want to update a JLabel with a text that contains data from the row I'm about to delete (probably there is a more elegant way).

This functionality should not be part of the TableModel. The button that invokes the delete logic should save the information you require before invoking the remove row method. Then the removeRow() code should remove the row from your rowData before firing the table rows deleted event.

> but it seems it happens most of the times after I edit a row, there's a column sorting active and then delete a row

You need to convert the row view to the row model. I think the code should be something like:

```
int modelRow = tableConvertRowIndexToModel( selectedRow );
rowData.remove(modelRow); 
fireTableRowsDeleted(modelRow, modelRow);
```

Comment: I'm always doing the view to model row conversion, but your other tip I think solved my problem. By saving the data, removing the row and firing the change, I don't seem to be getting the error. I think this was the cause: while the table was redrawn, I was also removing a row. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3):

you are getting

IndexOutOfBoundsException

from your stack trace.  That means you are referencing an index of an array which is greater than the length of the array.

This is probably occurring after you delete a row.  You need to make sure that when you delete a row, you note that the indexes of all the rows after the deleted row will change.

In other words, if you have

0 -- row1
1 -- row2
2 -- row3
3 -- row4

if you delete the row at index 1, your table looks like

0 -- row1
1 -- row3 <-- note the change
2 -- row4

Comment: Don't you mean "0 -- row1 1--row3 2--row4"?

Comment: yes, the error I understood, I couldn't figure out what was calling the getValueAt method, but I'm pretty sure now it was: table was redrawn because I fired the change of data and right after I was removing a row. But your example made me realise one more thing: the error never occurred when I deleted a row in the "middle" like your example. But always when it was the last row in the model (thus causing to call getValueAt() with an Index that is out of bounds). By removing a different row, the list is re-indexed and finds values where the "removed" index was. Thx for help guys.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, look at ContactsGUI.java line 1975. That is where the exception is being thrown. See what ArrayList is being referenced there. Then you'll have to look at where the size of that list is determined and how you decide which element to access from that list.

If you use an IDE, set a breakpoint on that line and debug the app - that may help a great deal.

Comment: I tried to set a breakpoint, but at that point I could only see that the method is about to try and get a value with an index that is out of bound. Camickr set me on the right track: was a bad idea to fire a change and than make the change.